# I want to design an app for Android 4+ but I have problems with the different sizes

Tags: android, screen

I need to redesign an app from IOS to Android (only the GUI, no coding), but it has to be compatible (from the design point of view) with ICS, JB and KitKat versions. 
I only designed apps for IOS not for android so, the problem is - I don't know what resolutions should I use (screen sizes in px and density - dpi). I understood that I have to do different sizes and I found [this](http://visual.ly/ios-android-design-guidelines-cheat-sheet) on google and [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html), but I still don't know where to begin from. Can anyone please tell me what sizes should I take in mind when designing the UI for the app? (like 480x800px at 320dpi, and so on).

Comment: See this : http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Everything about supporting multiple screen resolutions can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try having a look at below page by android:
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

For total understanding of UI design in android you can have a look over here
[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Android have no standard screen size predefined but things getting better in Andoid 3.2+ by new qulalifiers like sw (screens wider than ...). Before that you could only use size-buckets like large, normal, small which was not suitable for all ranges of android devices (in order to have a big picture, there are around 4000+ differnet android devices out there!). 
you can have a look over [official android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) for comprehensive details about this.

Comment: Thank you! From what I read I have to use only 2 sizes (small & normal screens), since the app isn't available for tablets.

Comment: i think it is not like this. Nowdays it is hard to find android phones with small screens but there are some. most of phones are in normal and large sizes however some are x-large. meanwhile if you read documentation you will understand that using these buckets may lead to some problems, so in some cases you should define layout for screens in different size ranges using pixels by (sw qualifier e.g.)

Comment: i updated the post and add official android blog link for a post about this topic. hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, I spoke to the developer and he explained to me what I have to do in order to get it right. I will do the UI starting with a design size like 480x800px (or anyother size from an android phone) and with the medium bucket dpi (160). After I finish the design, I take the elements that are not default and resize them to fit the other buckets (240/320/480dpi) and that's all. Thanks anyways for the prompt answers.